# Code execution stops due to loss of precesion error

Tags: java, cloud9

I am a noob so please excuse my noob indents if they are not to par. Any advice on indents would be hugely appreciated. So my problem is that after the switch statement the computer is not reading the next line of code. Which is the final invoice amount equation at the end and printing it to the screen. There is also an error saying:

`InvoiceApp.java:34: error: possible loss of precision
            switch(discountPercent)
               ^
      required: int
      found:    double
     1 error`

As you will see I have the variable discountPercent assigned as a double. So I am not sure why there is an error. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you. Here is my code thus far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InvoiceApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Declare variables and Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double subtotal, discountAmount, discountPercent, invoiceTotal;
        int customerType;


        //Display a welcome message
        System.out.println("Welcome to the invoice calculator app!");


       //Prompt user for customer type
       System.out.print("Please enter the customer type(1 for Silver, 2 for          Gold, or 3 for Platinum): ");


    //Read customer type
    customerType = input.nextInt();

    //Prompt user for subtotal   
    System.out.print("Please enter the subtotal amount: ");

    //Read subtotal
    subtotal = input.nextDouble();

    //Calculate Discount Rate

    switch(discountPercent)

    { //start switch block

    case 1:

    {

        if (subtotal >= 500)
            {
            discountPercent = .20;
            System.out.print("Your discount rate is .20"); 
            break;
            } 

        else if (subtotal >= 250)
            { 
            discountPercent = .15;
            System.out.print("Your discount rate is 15% !"); 
            break; 
            }

        else if (subtotal >= 100)
            {
            discountPercent = .10;
            System.out.print("Your discount rate is 10%!"); break;
            } 

        else if(subtotal < 100)
            {
            discountPercent = .0;
            System.out.print("Sorry, your discount rate is 0%!"); break;
            } 

        }//end of case one block
        case 2:
        {    
            {
            discountPercent = .2;
            System.out.print("Your discount rate is 20%!"); 
            break;
            } 
        }//end of case two block


        case 3:
        {

        if (subtotal >= 500)
            {
            discountPercent = .50;
            System.out.print("Woop woop, your discount rate is 50%!"); 
            break;
            }

        else if (subtotal < 500)
            {
            discountPercent = .40;
            System.out.print("Your discount rate is 40%!"); break;
            } 

        }//end of case three block
    default:
    {    
        {
        discountPercent = .5;
        System.out.print("Congratulations! Your discount rate is 50 %! ");                                   } 
    }

 }//end of switch discountPercent

//Calculate Invoice Total
discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
invoiceTotal = subtotal - discountAmount;

System.out.println("Total: " + invoiceTotal);

//Display thank you message
System.out.println("Thank you!");


//Format and display the results
System.out.print("Jump around! Jump around! Your invoice total is: " + invoiceTotal);


}//end of main
}//end of class
```

Comment: this is a compile error.  This code can not run.

Comment: `switch` won't let use a `double`, you'll have to use a `if` statement

Comment: thanks guys, so I can't use a double in a switch statement at all?

Comment: Also some of your text output in your system.out's don't match the discount %'s.

Comment: Exactly. And please understand : such things are super basic. You learn about them by studying your books; not by asking us about things that are well documented a zillion times out there.

Comment: double to int - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue()

Comment: GhostCat that is good to know, I have already run it a few times because I thought the error was just a suggestion, that would make sense though because it's telling me something is probably wrong, i fixed the print statements to match, wow don't know how i even did that Artemis, embarrassing but thank you

Comment: Scary that was not my main issue, the real issue is that after the switch statement the program does not move to the next operation

Answer (score 2):

The switch statement won't working with double.

Please refer this tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>       types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum
>       Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap
>       certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer
>       (discussed in Numbers and Strings).